# Autohotkey Keystroke/hotkey problem

Tags: autohotkey

This was a comment i left for someone and realize it is a full blown question. It is to remap a game key from numpad4 to something i quickly can press.

I couldnt figure this out. It seems like it doesnt recognize shift (i tried using shift o and then O:: with no luck). Then i tried ::df:: (as in press them at the same time to trigger) but it looks like it triggers when i write df then a non alphabet character after it. And shift, ctrl, etc which i can hit with my pinky quickly doesnt count. How do i write a trigger i can hit quickly with my left hand? Currently my file is ::df::Send {Numpad4}

Comment: `::df::...` is an AutoHotkey [hotstring](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm). But it sounds like you want to make a [hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) like `+o::Send {Numpad4}` or `d & f::Send {Numpad4}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::df::...` type of definition is an AutoHotkey [hotstring](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm), which is used for expanding abbreviations automatically, but it sounds like you want to stick with [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

As explained on the hotkeys page, AutoHotkey uses special symbols for modifier keys: `^` for Ctrl, `+` for Shift, `!` for Alt, and `#` for the Windows key.

You can use `&` to make other keys act as modifiers, for example `d & f` will make the d key become a modifier key. But this causes the d key to lose its original function. As explained on the hotkeys page, you can use something like `d::Send d` to have the d key function normally when you *release* the key.

So to do what you want, you might use something like `+o::Send {Numpad4}` or `d & f::Send {Numpad4}`.

Comment: ah, you didnt need to write that much. The comment you left really was long enough lol. Thanks -edit- i am glad you added the 4 modifier symbols. That will help in future reference.